# Show that a vector space $V$ is isomorphic to $U\times(V/U)$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a vector space and $U$ is a subspace of $V$, show that $V$ is isomorphic to $U\times(V/U)$ (The direct product of $V$ and $V/U$). I have worked out a solution to the case where $V$ is finite, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding a solution for the general case.

Comment: How did you do the finite-dimensional case? Probably the method extends to the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: Hint: choose a basis for $U$, then extend it to a basis for $V$. The part of the basis which does not belong to $U$ will span a complementary subspace.

Comment: Can we prove this without AOC in the infinite-dimensional case?

Comment: @Christoph I know this is old, but I doubt it.

Comment: @JustinCampbell how can we choose a basis of $U$ when we don't know if it's finite dimensional?